Adding strings into an empty array via inputbox

When a button is clicked, an inputbox will load for the user to enter a string. The inputbox will reappear for a new input unitl "!" is entered. Right now, I have each input stored in a listbox but I want every input to be stored in an array.
How can can I do this?
I tried using reDim but that doesn't seem to work.

Please do not post code as a picture. Edit your question and include the code as text.

You haven't shown any code using ReDim or told us what happened when you used it. You haven't told us what's wrong with the code you have. You haven't told us or shown us where words is declared. Arrays don't have an Add method so it's obviously not an array. You should be using a List(Of String) and the AddRange to add the items to the ListBox.

The following may be of interest: Objects and classes in Visual Basic, How to: Create a List of Items,

If one looks at the documentation for ListBox, one sees Inheritance Object -> MarshalByRefObject -> Component -> ListControl -> ListBox. Click on ListControl. On the left-side, expand Properties. Refer to the documentation for  DisplayMember, ValueMember, and SelectedValue.

The following may also be of interest: User control overview (Windows Forms .NET) and How to create a user control (Windows Forms .NET and Send data within Child Forms

Based on your description, you want to store your input string into an array.
You could convert the Listbox.Items to a string array by using the following code after you add the string to the listbox
Dim str() As String = ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String).ToArray()

